# Interpolation between 3600X1 and 3600X30 matrixes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the tVec vector 1x3600 which is the time and the corresponding velocities of wave for 30 pieces dz in the matrix `uWave` 30x3600

I want to interpolate from random t.The problem is tha I want to create a matrix 30x1 which is the corresponding velocity and its 30 components dz.

I tried this one but it does not work.

```
uWaveinter(:,30)=interp1(tVec,uWave,t)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `interp1` accepts a 1D vectors for x,y inputs. In your case you can simply use a for-loop:

```
for n=1:30
   uWaveinter(n,:)=interp1(tVec,uWave(n,:),t);
end
```

where `t`  can be a single point or a vector of points...